# Use dask to map over an array and return a dataframe

Tags: python, dask

I am using dask and zarr to operate over some very large images.

I have a pipeline set up that performs some transformations to these images and I would then like to measure properties of the image using the regionprops and regionprops_table functions from skimage. This takes a matrix as an input and returns a data frame. I can't use map_overlap as this rewuires a matrix to be returned but I would like something sematically similar to this:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import pandas as pd

mask = np.zeros((1000, 1000), dtype=int)
mask[100:200, 100:200] = 1
mask[300:400, 300:400] = 2
mask[500:600, 500:600] = 3
mask = da.from_array(mask, chunks=(200, 200))

def get_data_frame(mask):
    res = regionprops_table(mask, properties=('label', 'area', 'eccentricity'))
    df = pd.DataFrame(res)
    return df

mask.map_overlap(get_data_frame, depth=50, boundary=None).compute()
```

Returning either a pandas data frame or a dask data frame but I would like each chunk to be dealt with in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use overlap and to_delayed to convert the Dask Array to Delayed objects:

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
from dask import delayed
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from skimage.measure import regionprops_table

mask = np.zeros((1000, 1000), dtype=int)
mask[100:200, 100:200] = 1
mask[300:400, 300:400] = 2
mask[500:600, 500:600] = 3
mask = da.from_array(mask, chunks=(200, 200))
mask

def get_data_frame(mask):
    res = regionprops_table(mask, properties=('label', 'area', 'eccentricity'))
    df = pd.DataFrame(res)
    return df

mask_overlaped = da.overlap.overlap(mask, depth=50, boundary=None)
delayed_chunks = mask_overlaped.to_delayed()
delayed_frames = []

# there is probably a better way to iterate here
for i in range(delayed_chunks.shape[0]):
    for j in range(delayed_chunks.shape[1]):
        delayed_frames.append(delayed(get_data_frame)(delayed_chunks[i][j]))

ddf = dd.from_delayed(delayed_frames, meta={'label': 'int64', 'area': 'float64', 'eccentricity': 'float64'})

ddf.compute()
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm no expert in Dask, but I hope to help anyway.*

As I understand `map_overlap()` returns (by default) an array similar to the *chunk* giving as input (eg, same shape). This is *not* clearly state by the function's documentation, but it's implicit in the docs about the `meta` parameter of `map_blocks()` (which map_overlap uses internally).

See the respective docs:

- https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.map_overlap.html
- https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.map_blocks.html

*In other words:* **you cannot return a DataFrame** from `map_overlap`

> you can *adjust* the attributes of the output array through `map_overlap`/`map_blocks` parameters, but you cannot avoid it and try to return something completely different (e.g, DataFrame).

### Proposed solution/work-around:

I would still use `map_overlap` (for its support for `depth`/`boundary`, which is super handy) but redirect the result from `regionprops_table` to another data structure from the outer/global scope.

Here is what I mean using your example:

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

mask = np.zeros((1000, 1000), dtype=int)
mask[100:200, 100:200] = 1
mask[300:400, 300:400] = 2
mask[500:600, 500:600] = 3
mask = da.from_array(mask, chunks=(200, 200))

import pandas as pd
from skimage.measure import regionprops_table

prop_dfs = []

def get_data_frame(mask, block_id=None): 
    """
    'block_id' to know where we are in the array.
    We will used it to identify region-props in the final table.
    """
    # avoid processing on 0-d arrays
    if mask.size > (200*200): 
      res = regionprops_table(mask, properties=('label', 'area', 'eccentricity'))

      # Include "x" and "y" in the final table
      res.update({'x':block_id[0], 'y':block_id[1]})
      prop_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(res))

      # I'm returning the input just to avoid complains/errors
      return mask

mask.map_overlap(get_data_frame, depth=50, boundary=None).compute()

df = pd.concat(prop_dfs).set_index(['x','y']).sort_index()
```

Which would render the following table:

```py
print(df)

     label   area  eccentricity
x y                            
0 0      1  10000      0.000000
  1      1   5000      0.866069
1 0      1   5000      0.866069
  1      1   2500      0.000000
  1      2  10000      0.000000
  2      2   5000      0.866069
2 1      2   5000      0.866069
  2      2   2500      0.000000
  2      3  10000      0.000000
  3      3   5000      0.866069
3 2      3   5000      0.866069
  3      3   2500      0.000000
```

> Obs: clearly, that is a bottleneck when we use a (serial) List, `prop_dfs`, to collect all those results generated in parallel. There may be a better (also parallel insertion) way of doing that which I don't know about right now.

Hope that helped. Comments on how to improve this (hopefully) solution are very welcome.

Comment: As prop_dfs is a local variable, I think this won't work in multi-processing or distributed environments.

Comment: In distributed systems, will not, for sure. It works in multi-core systems but imposes a tight bottleneck by all means. Your solution (I believe) addresses it properly.